# Refrencing Pointers In Structures After reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, header, portable-executable

I am trying to copy the data of a pointer to a structure but am having issues. I commented where it crashes the program and where i am interacting with the pointer. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinNT.h>
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "NtStructs.h"

struct Resource
{
    WORD Id;
    DWORD Name;
    DWORD NameIsString;
    DWORD OffsetToData;
    PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY DataEntry;
};

std::vector<Resource> listResources;

PBYTE GetBaseAddress()
{
    return static_cast<LPBYTE>(NtCurrentTeb()->Peb->ImageBaseAddress);
}

void DumpMyResources()
{
    // Get Self
    PBYTE data                              = reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(GetBaseAddress()));

    // Get The DOS Header
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH                   = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(data);

    // Get The NT Header Using 'e_lfanew' As A Pointer To The NT Header
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH                   = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(data + IDH->e_lfanew);

    // Get The Resource Directory Using NT Header -> Optional Header -> Data Directory
    PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY IRD           = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY>(data + INH->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].VirtualAddress);

    // Convert Resource Directory To PBYTE
    PBYTE resData                           = reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(IRD);

    // Entry Point To Directory
    PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY IRDE    = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY>(IRD + 1);


    // Loop All Resource Directories
    for (int i = 0; i < IRD->NumberOfIdEntries; i++)
    {
        // Find Directory We Want (Which Is 10 Because We Are Only Interested In RT_RCDATA)
        if (IRDE[i].Id == 10)
        {
            // Enter This Directory
            IRD = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY>(resData + IRDE[i].OffsetToDirectory);
            IRDE = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY>(IRD + 1);

            for (int j = 0; j < IRD->NumberOfIdEntries; j++)
            {
                Resource hResource;

                hResource.Id            = IRDE[j].Id;
                hResource.Name          = IRDE[j].Name;
                hResource.NameIsString  = IRDE[j].NameIsString;
                hResource.OffsetToData  = IRDE[j].OffsetToData;

                // This line needs to be fixed. I dont want a pointer, I want to copy the data from pointer to struct.
                hResource.DataEntry = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY>(resData + IRDE->OffsetToData);

                listResources.push_back(hResource);
            }
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    DumpMyResources();

    for (auto hRes : listResources)
    {
        printf("[Found] ID: %i\n",                  hRes.Id);
        printf("[Found] Name: %ld\n",               hRes.Name);
        printf("[Found] NameIsString: %ld\n",       hRes.NameIsString);
        printf("[Found] OffsetToData: %#X\n",       hRes.OffsetToData);

        // The output(s) below cause program to crash
        printf("[Found] Size: %ld\n",               hRes.DataEntry->Size);
        printf("[Found] CodePage: %ld\n",           hRes.DataEntry->CodePage);
        printf("[Found] OffsetToData: %#X\n",       hRes.DataEntry->OffsetToData);
        printf("[Found] Reserved: %ld\n",           hRes.DataEntry->Reserved);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

How can I copy the data from where the pointer points to to the struct?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c]?

Comment: Suspect: you use `IRDE[j].OffsetToData` and then `IRDE->OffsetToData`.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a C++ feature, not a C feature,  please remove the 'c' tag from the question

Comment: You should have added the **C**obol tag, too. It also starts with the letter "C". Or Java, this also uses these fancy curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you can make a copy of the data by changing the type of `DataEntry` to `IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY`, then change your assignment to dereference the computed pointer:

```
hResource.DataEntry = *reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY>(resData + IRDE[j].OffsetToData);
```

(incorporating the fix mentioned by Jarod42 in a comment).  Change the uses of `DataEntry` to use a `.` instead of `->`.